# How to get only link from Google search page in Python?

Tags: python

I've tried many ways but failed. I was able to fetch the links but not just the domain names. I want Google to save the domain list from all the pages in one file. Ex: (https://www.google.com). Here is my code include and also my output picture.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


class males:
    def googleurlcode(self):
        user_input = input("Enter something for Search : ")
        print("Wait...")

        google_search = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + user_input)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(google_search.text, 'html.parser')

        search_results = soup.find_all("a")

        for link in search_results:
            print(re.split(":(?=http)", link["href"].replace("/url?q=", "")))


dahah = males()

while True:
    answer = input('Do you want to continue[y/n]?:')
    if answer.lower().startswith("y"):
        dahah.googleurlcode()
        # print("ok, carry on then")
    elif answer.lower().startswith("n"):
        print("ok, Good By")
        exit()
```

[Output from me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQCOG.jpg)

Comment: Try to use google api to do what you want: https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/quickstart/quickstart-python

Answer (score 0):

use the urllib library to open the links, then you can fetch the domain name

```
def get_domain_name(link):
    OpenedPage = request.urlopen(request.Request(link,
                      headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome'})).read().decode("utf-8")
    domain_name = BeautifulSoup(OpenedPage, "lxml") #.find('Domain_Name')
    return domain_name
```

Comment: I also used your code. But this is not happening. I wanted to do a Google search for the total number of pages that will come. I will take the link to that domain. Will create a new file. Where all domain names will be save this file.

Comment: but where I used this function?